# Is there an online resource for caravan "pit stops" around Europe?

Tags: europe, online-resources, caravans

I was wondering if there is such thing as a caravan guide for Europe. Particularly Spain and France. But other countries would be very welcome.

This resource would have information about places where caravans can stop/park and/or spend the night. Place with toilets and showers for caravanists (and others, does not need to be exclusive).

Optionaly but very welcome, would identify scenic routes and particulary beautiful places to spend the night (if allowed).

Ratings and comments on the spots would be, of course, a big plus.

I am aware that some highways in France offer good conditions for stoping. I am looking for these, but also, and preferably for the ones outside highways.

Comment: What you are asking looks pretty much like campsites with spaces for those staying just one night. Do you have requirements that makes clear you look for something other than a campsite?

Comment: Yes. In some countries there are areas specifically for caravans. In some places even free with toilets. They don't provide much more than parking spots.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are a fair number of resources like this.

Starting at the obvious place, [the Caravan Club of the UK has a list of European campsites](http://www.caravanclub.co.uk/overseas-holidays/sites) inspected by the club. Most of them will have the facilities you want, and you can check each one individually.

In Europe the term 'campsite' usually includes places which take caravans, and most campsites accept caravans (and RVs/campervans as well). Your best approach is to locate appropriate campgrounds, and if in doubt confirm that caravans are accepted. Again virtually all are going to have toilets and showers.

Without recommendation, here is [a link to get you started](http://www.uk-sites.com/caravanandcampsites.eu/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean places where you can spend the night that aren't campsites: I haven't come across such places in France. There are lots of overnight sites for campervans (aire de camping-car), but these generally don't offer toilets and showers, and have parking spots sized for campervans instead of car+caravan combinations. So in France you'd have to use campsites. If you want to stay somewhere cheap, a web search for 'camping municipal' will get you lots of basic, inexpensive campsites.

In the UK it's simple: no camping at all outside campsites. I've no experience with other countries.

Comment: http://www.campervanlife.com/locations/europe/1st-timer-tips] Some advice from the link about sleeping overnight in a campervan in France mentions not to stop overnight on French Auto Route aires - particularly the A7 and A9. It also says 'Don't be scared of free camping: people very rarely experience any trouble. Stopping at a beautiful beach, lakeside or mountain rest area, and then stopping for the night, week, or even a month, is a fantastic experience.' This might be an alternative way of finding rest spots at a fraction of the price of caravan sites.